# Convert string to unsigned char array/byte array

Tags: c++, arrays

How could I convert the following string:

```
std::string str = "x89x30x50";
```

to this following unsigned char array/byte array with escape sequences:

```
unsigned char char_arr[1024] = "\x89\x30\x50";
```

Comment: What do you want to do? The string `\xas\xdf\xtg` is not the byte representation of `xasxdfxtg`.

Comment: These are not valid escape sequences. They have to be of the form `\x__` where `__` is some (two digit) hexvalue.

Comment: I edited to represent hex values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to split a string of hexadecimal values (prefixed by 'x') into byte values.

You could achieve this by tokenizing the string (with a delimiter of 'x') and converting each token to the byte value:

Something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "x89x30x50";
    unsigned char char_arr[1024] = "";
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    std::string token;
    int i = 0;
    while (std::getline(iss, token, 'x'))
    {
        if (token.empty()) continue;
        char_arr[i++] = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::stoi(token, nullptr, 16));
    }
    //char_arr = {0x89,0x30,0x50,0,0,...}
}
```